# iOS Data didn't sent to custom TableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm working on a project that using a custom TableCell. Here's my code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"customScoreCell";
ScoreTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (!cell)
    cell = [[ScoreTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


cell.classNameLabel.text = courseNameArray[indexPath.row];
cell.creditLabel.text = courseCreditArray[indexPath.row];
cell.scoreLabel.text = courseScoreArray[indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"%@",courseScoreArray[indexPath.row]);


        return cell;  }
```

[image]
There're output from the NSLOG, but I cannot get that data to show in those three labels in my custom cell. I can see the cells after I run it, but it only shows same info that I put them in the attribute inspector when I created the custom cell. Anyone got the solution?

**UPDATE** I tried changing `cell.creditLabel.text = courseCreditArray[indexPath.row];` to `cell.textLabel.text = courseCreditArray[indexPath.row];` and this showed.

[image]

and This is the data I wanna show in where "credit" is showing.
and This is how I setup the IBOutlet:
[image]

Comment: where you add the values into **courseNameArray** on that place assign **[yourtableview relaoddata]**

Comment: Have to connected labels using IBOutlet?

Comment: what the result u get in cell for row at index path NSLog(@"%@",courseScoreArray[indexPath.row]);

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I got the data I want and when I scroll the tableview, I can see all the data, but I still cannot get it to show on the cell

Comment: try this cell.classNameLabel.text = courseNameArray[indexPath.row];  change into cell.textLabel.text = courseNameArray[indexPath.row]; and tell to me what the result u get

Comment: Can you share screenshot of your outlets which you have assigned to lables?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I have upload the pic of my screenshot in the post, please take a look

Comment: After seeing your updated question. There must be a problem with your outlets.

Comment: now u got it na where the problem occurs, problem not in your tableview check that your custom cell class reuse identifier and your IBOutlet is given correct or not, etc

Comment: if you thing you did in correct no problem, remove the IBOutlet in from attribute and add again once no problem , surely works

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I have upload the pic of my IBOutlet setup. I put the IBOutlet in my custom cell class, is that correct?

Comment: @Gati I have upload the pic. Please take a look. Thank you

Comment: ya correct bro , now run your project it working fine

Comment: Name of your cell identifier?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I delete all my IBOutlet and added them again, still won't show the data...I'm very confused

Comment: @Gati indentifier is correct, I checked them 5 times, and I directly copied it from the Attribute menu.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Problem solved...damn you XCode...After clean, delete the app in the simuator and run the program, it worked...Thank you very much man

Comment: hmm, K have a nice day bro...,small mistakes always happen in working time, if we go through in step by step we can easily solve the issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code is correct, after clean, delete the app in the simulator and then run the program again, it worked... I have no idea why the two times I did the same thing before I send this post didn't work...So confusing

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the cell Identifier and also your implementation of the following functions

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView//No compulsion if you have only 1 section.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section //Compulsory to specify the number of rows.
```

Cheers!